# Changed max_allowed_packet and still receiving 'Packet Too Large' error

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump, mysql-5

I use mysqldump to create a flat file for backup purposes.  I have used this file to recreate the database on an alternate server.  I ran the import process through ssh on the command line and I received multiple `Packet too Large` errors.

I restarted mysql with a much larger max_allowed_packet (i.e.- 1000M) and still received the error.  I even attempted setting the max_allowed_packet in the import file, still received the error.

Is there a way to ensure the max_allowed_packet is set and/or use mysqldump that will create a file that does not cause this problem?

For reference:

the uncompressed mysqldump file is ~2GB

database type is INNODB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first I thought about was what [**max_allowed_packet**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) actually controls. Here is what I found:

According to the [page 99 of "Understanding MySQL Internals" (ISBN 0-596-00957-7)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596009577), here are paragraphs 1-3 explaining it:

> MySQL network communication code was
>   written under the assumption that
>   queries are always reasonably short,
>   and therefore can be sent to and
>   processed by the server in one chunk,
>   which is called a *packet* in MySQL
>   terminology. The server allocates the
>   memory for a temporary buffer to store
>   the packet, and it requests enough to
>   fit it entirely. This architecture
>   requires a precaution to avoid having
>   the server run out of memory---a cap
>   on the size of the packet, which this
>   option accomplishes.
>
> The code of interest in relation to
>   this option is found in
>   **sql/net_serv.cc**. Take a look at **my_net_read()**, then follow the call to **my_real_read()** and pay
>   particular attention to
>   **net_realloc()**.
>
> This variable also limits the length
>   of a result of many string functons.
>   See **sql/field.cc** and
>   **sql/intem_strfunc.cc** for details.

Given that definition of max_allowed_packet, I then discovered something else from ServerFault: [innodb_log_file_size and innodb_log_buffer_size combined must be larger than ten times your biggest blob object if you have a lot of large ones](https://serverfault.com/questions/3952/what-should-i-know-before-going-live-with-an-innodb-database/3979#3979)

Keeping these two things in mind, I would increase innodb_log_file_size in /etc/my.cnf to the max size allowed for it, 2047M. This of course requires the following

```
service mysql stop
rm -f /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile*
service mysql start
```

This will accommodate any big blobs you may have in your data.

Comment: Curious as to where that 10x comes from - is it just a rule of thumb or is there code in MySQL that say allocates 10 fixed buffers so you need 10 to ensure that 1 of them is big enough?

Comment: Is this book authoritative?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL's `max_allowed_packet` still has to be within the limits of the shell that started it - does `ulimit -a` show that `data seg size` is unlimited?

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, `max_allowed_packet` is ignored by `mysqldump` -- by [design](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=9753)? The actual complement is `net_buffer_length`. So instead try

```
mysqldump --net_buffer_length=100k -u root -p databasename > dump.sql
```

Comment: That's very enlightening !!! Since the bug report discusses the extended insert in conjunction with this problem, maybe doing --skip-extended-insert may compensate some but will surely generate a larger mysqldump. +1 for You finding this diamond in the rough that Oracle will leave for dead !!!

Comment: --skip-extended-insert definitely works, but on my database slowed down restore by 100x making it unusable.

Comment: I'm sorry, my condolences. Maybe have mysqldump create CSV files and try loading them back using LOAD DATA INFILE and increasing bulk_insert_buffer_size to 1G or 2G. Hey, you never know !!!