# Why max_allowed_packet is larger in mysqldump than mysqld in my.cnf?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysqldump

If you look at the sample config such as `/usr/share/mysql/my-large.cnf`, you will find..

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 1M

[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet = 16M
```

What is the point?

Because when you export a dump using `mysqldump` with `max_allowed_packet` that might not able import successfully to the current mysql? E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93128/mysql-error-1153-got-a-packet-bigger-than-max-allowed-packet-bytes

Comment: I wrote about what the MySQL Packet is back in April 2011 : http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/2383/877. Please read it.

Answer (score 4):

The `max_allowed_packet` variable limits the size of a single result set. In the `[mysqld]` section, any normal connection can only get `1M` worth of data in a single query.
In `mysqldump` you typically produce "extended INSERT" queries, where you list multiple rows within the same `INSERT` command. It's better, then, to have this variable set high.

The above is a brief explanation. Now, as for your question "What is the point?" -- there is no clear answer. The `my-XXXXX.cnf` set of files are long since outdated, and have their issues, including recommendations which are commonly not agreed upon (like the amount of memory you should allocate to the `innodb_buffer_pool_size`). So take it as a general starting point. In particular, these settings relate to systems with very low memory available (like `128M` RAM), so the numbers don't really apply to today's hardware.

One could argue that you won't necessarily import the dump into same server, so possible to another server with higher setting for `max_allowed_packet`.

As a side note, I usually set `max_allowed_packet` to very high values, like `32M` or `64M`. As opposed to other variables like `sort_buffer_size`, with `max_allowed_packet` you only pay for what you need. So a connection will not allocate the full `64M` if it doesn't have to.

A `1M` limit means you could have some row with some `TEXT` or `BLOB`, possibly larger than `1M`, and in such case, you would actually be unable to read that row.

Comment: +1 for just setting it higher. I usually like setting to 256M for starters. I rarely have to exceed that.

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc [1]:

```
When creating multiple-row INSERT statements 
(as with the --extended-insert or --opt option), mysqldump creates rows 
up to net_buffer_length length.
```

And since the limit of `net_buffer_length` is 1M, the configuration above is perfectly fine even the `max_allowed_packet` of `mysqldump` is 16M .

[1] http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_net_buffer_length

Comment: Thanks for docs, but if employing `-c` switch together with `-e` one still needs to lower `net_buffer_length`.