# Max_packet_allowed setting for Windows 7

Tags: mysql

We have windows xp machine with older version of mysql. So when we need to import huge data we just set the max_allowed_packet=1500M in the C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1 . Now we loaded the latest mysql 5.6.12. We are trying to import the same date and we find there are few my.cnf file on is in the program file and another in programme data both change yet we cant import the same data. Where else to change even after the change we started the service by going into the admistrative tool.

Comment: What does `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'basedir';` return?  Is there a file called 'my.cnf' in that directory?

Comment: @It says this C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\ and here is a filed named as my-default and in it also I have put infact max_allowed_packet=2000M but yet it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum size for a MySQL Packet is [**1G according to the MySQL Documentation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet). See my post [Changed max_allowed_packet and still receiving 'Packet Too Large' error](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/886/changed-max-allowed-packet-and-still-receiving-packet-too-large-error/2383#2383)  in case you are dealing with big BLOBs.

If you are importing a large database from Windows. see my past posts

- `Jul 24, 2013` : [Moving MySql from windows server to linux (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818106/moving-mysql-from-windows-server-to-linux/17823213#17823213)
- `Apr 17, 2011` : [How can I optimize a mysqldump of a large database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-can-i-optimize-a-mysqldump-of-a-large-database/2227#2227)

Comment: what surprise me it works well on windows xp but on not on windows 7 another thing the file in this location C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\  is my-default do you think I should change it to my.cnf? My file is pure text data no blob and is very basic data just with few hundred thousand rows. Is it because I am using sqlyog to import in the data ?