# SQL Error (2027): Malformed packet

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have a `mysql` database (`Version 5.6.23-log running on windows`) that is set up for use with Teamcity. When running a command against it using HeidiSQL I am getting an error:

> SQL Error (2027): Malformed packet

This error only occurs if the result set is more than a certain number of rows (using LIMIT 14561 rows works, 14562 gives this error).

I believe this error is not due to Heidi since TeamCity is failing to start when running the same command.

I assume it is something to do with the data size becoming too large and something failing but I can't find any way to identify more specifically what the problem is and thus how to fix it.

If anybody can tell me what I can do to prevent this problem or at the very least how I might be able to better diagnose this problem I'd be most grateful.

Comment: So it sounds like it works with smaller datasets, could it be how TeamCity is setup? I ran across this in research: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331755/how-do-i-setup-teamcity-for-public-access-over-https]

Comment: I don't *think* it would be to do with team city since I get an error when using HeidiSQL (which is a SQL client) to do the query and that is not touching any Teamcity code at all. It is possible it is something to do with the data that teamcity stores but I think it more likely that there is some setting to do with maximum recordset size or something like that that I am missing (or a bug that only happens when a large dataset is returned). The linked question doesn't seem to help at all - its more about port conflicts on the web server part than db problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found that if I dumped the data out of one database and into another on a different machine that things seemed to work. I thus decided to do a compare of the two config files and update values that were different. In doing so I updated the following:

- `tmp_table_size` from `5M` to `19M`
- `myisam_sort_buffer_size` from `8M` to `30M`
- `read_buffer_size` from `0` to `59K`
- `read_rnd_buffer_size` from `0` to `256K`
- `sort_buffer_size` from `0` to `256K`
- `query_cache_type` from `1` to `0`

Doing this fixed my issues. I'm sure not all of them are needed so I would be happy for somebody to explain why this fixed my problem in a better answer (and will gladly transfer acceptance to them in that case).

Comment: ZERO for read_buffer_size, etc???  Yikes.

Comment: I have to admit I assumed those zeros were some kind of "use default value" type zeros. Am I to take it that they actually said "use no buffers"? In my defence I didn't set these up! ;-)

Comment: The manual is unclear on the issue.  It does state a "minimum" value.  Perhaps 0 is replaced by the minimum.  You can discover the active value by doing `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer_size';`.

Comment: Thanks Rick. I'm not going to touch the server again now its working though! Curious though I am possibly breaking it in the name of SCIENCE! is not on my todo list today. :)

Answer (score 4):

My guess would be that you have TEXT/BLOB data and that the row data in the 14562 row is bigger than your current [MySQL Packet](https://superuser.com/questions/273730/what-does-the-mysql-max-allowed-packet-setting-actually-control/273833#273833), which is sized by [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet).

## MySQL Perspective

You need to reserve more space for [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet)

- `Jul 29, 2013` : [Max_packet_allowed setting for Windows 7](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47180/max-packet-allowed-setting-for-windows-7/47190#47190)
- `Jul 03, 2013` : [What max_allowed_packet is big enough, and why do I need to change it?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45665/what-max-allowed-packet-is-big-enough-and-why-do-i-need-to-change-it/45667#45667)
- `Jun 12, 2012` : [MySQL Error Reading Communication Packets](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19135/mysql-error-reading-communication-packets/19139#19139)

Your InnoDB Redo Logs (sized by [innodb_log_file_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size)) may need to be increased as well. [I first learned of it (in relation to the MySQL Packet) from ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/3952/what-should-i-know-before-going-live-with-an-innodb-database/3979#3979). I refer to that ServerFault post in some of my posts:

- `Apr 27, 2011` : [Changed max_allowed_packet and still receiving 'Packet Too Large' error](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/886/changed-max-allowed-packet-and-still-receiving-packet-too-large-error/2383#2383)
- `Aug 01, 2011` : [How does max_allowed_packet affect the  backup and restore of a database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4230/how-does-max-allowed-packet-affect-the-backup-and-restore-of-a-database/4231#4231)

I would max out the [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) to 1G and [resize your redo logs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size) to 1.5G

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 1G
innodb_log_file_size = 1536M
```

Next, run this to purge all transactions out of the redo logs:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 0;
```

Then, restart mysql (which is required).

## Note to everyone running MySQL 5.5 and prior

MySQL 5.6 will handle resizing logs for you when restarting. Previous versions of MySQL require that you do that manually. Your steps after changing `my.cnf` and setting `innodb_fast_shutdown` to 0, you would do the following

```
service mysql stop
mv ib_logfile0 ib_logfile0.bak
mv ib_logfile1 ib_logfile1.bak
service mysql start
```

## HeidiSQL Perspective

One very common complaint is Error 2027, particularly with using `LOAD DATA INFILE`

Some have suggested using older versions of `libmysql.dll`

- [HeidiSQL 8.1 released](http://www.heidisql.com/forum.php?t=13487)
- [sql error(2007) Malformed packet](http://www.heidisql.com/forum.php?t=13454)

Some suspect a character set issue : [Error Code: 2027 Malformed packet](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,615588,616141#msg-616141)

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: I would also make sure you are using the latest version of HeidiSQL, especially using the latest libmysql.dll. You may need to rollback to previous version of HeidiSQL.

Comment: That looks like loads of useful information to be getting on with. One thing I should have noted is that it is not the specific 14562nd row that is causing the problem. If I order it differently it is still the same number of rows that causes a problem. I'll look through the links you've provided though, they look really helpful. :)

Comment: As an additional note if I use `LIMIT 14561` then it works but if I use `LIMIT 14561,1` it fails. This suggests its the amount of data in memory that is causing the problem . Likewise removing the `order by` clause allows me to fetch more rows and changing the order by to a larger field (eg a VARCHAR(255) instead of a bigint) then I can fetch less data. It really seems like it is hitting some size limit but I've upped the max_allowed_packet to 1G (and no single blob data should be that big anyway). Is there somewhere else that memory is limited in the server per request or something?

Comment: In case you are interested I found a solution. Sadly none of the things you suggested seemed to help. On looking the datatables combined were less than 10M on disk. A comparison of config files between two servers allowed me to find some config values to update that seems to have fixed it though I will admit to not having a clue why. :) Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Don't you need an extra step when changing `innodb_log_file_size`?

Comment: @RickJames adding extra steps now. Please let me any additional steps if I missed anything.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above advices were helpful in my case. Turns out it was a bug in MySQL and not a wrong configuration as suggested in the other answers. Changing `max_allowed_packet` etc had no effect whatsoever.

Then I found this: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77298

> "This is duplicate of internal bug Bug#20895852 which is fixed. Noted
>   in 5.6.25, 5.7.8, 5.8.0 changelogs."
>
> For small values of the read_rnd_buffer_size system variable, 
>   internal caching of temporary results could fail and cause query 
>   execution failure.

I went from `5.6.22` to `5.6.26` and the issue went away without any configuration changes.

All I did was

```
brew upgrade mysql
```

and restart the server in a new terminal tab using

```
mysql.server restart
```

That was all.

Comment: Good find! I've taken the liberty of trying to update your answer with the actual bug explanation from that report. Given that `read_rnd_buffer_size` was one of the values I updated I am pretty sure that this is the bug I was running into. :)

Answer (score 1):

Same issue haunted my team for a while, and there's very little useful information about it on the web. We spent a lot of time troubleshooting the issue - and FINALLY found solution that solved it (at least - for our team)!

We found that Django sets "charset" option to "utf8" for database connections by default. During troubleshooting we used two separate database connection objects: one created for us by Django, and another - created manually using direct _mysql.connect() command. When we executed same exact query using both connection objects - the one created by Django resulted in "***django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2027, 'Malformed packet')***" (which is exactly what we were getting in our API), but the second connection (manual) - worked without any issues. Further comparison of the two connection objects (we actually had to use Python debugger "pdb" and set breakpoint within django.db.backends.mysql.base.py for that) - revealed that Django creates connection by passing "charset":"utf8", while manual _mysql connection - uses "latin1". As soon as we added "charset":"latin1" to DATABASES["default"]["OPTIONS"] within our settings.py - this error disappeared.

To summarize, solution (for us) was to explicitly set "charset":"latin1" within "OPTIONS" config section of DATABASES configuration - for every database alias. I can not say for sure that this will work for everyone who experiences this error - but it certainly works for us.

In general, any MySQL connection that uses "utf8" charset would perform the same way (generate this error); replacing that with "latin1" should solve it.